# Why do my other nav links affect the ones with drop downs?

Tags: html, css, zurb-foundation

I can't seem to find out why my nav links without dropdowns are affecting the ones that have them. They don't share a same class so that's not the issue.

I made sure in the CSS file to target the drop down links correctly. I feel like I'm missing something rather obvious here. For your viewing pleasure: [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/gtne4fmn/6/)

```css
.dropdown li .menu {
  display: none;
}

.dropdown:hover li .menu {
  display: block;
  float: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.0.8/js/all.js"></script>
<div class="dropdown">
  <ul class="menu dropdown menu-hover-lines" data-dropdown-menu>
    <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Collections</a>
      <ul class="menu">
        <li><a href="#">Autos</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Models</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Nature</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Extreme Sports</a></li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#">About me</a></li>
    <li><a href="">Get in touch</a>
      <ul class="menu">
        <li><a href="#"><i class="fas fa-envelope fa-2x" data-toggle="tooltip" title="Email me!"></i></a></li>
        <li><a href="http://twitter.com"><i class="fab fa-twitter fa-2x" data-toggle="tooltip" title="Tweet me!"></i></a></li>
        <li><a href="http://instagram.com"><i class="fab fa-instagram fa-2x" data-toggle="tooltip" title="Message me!"></i></a></li>
      </ul>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change this

```
.dropdown:hover li .menu {
  display: block;
  float: none;
}
```

to this

```
.dropdown li:hover .menu {
  display: block;
  float: none;
}
```

**Snippet**

```css
.dropdown li .menu {
  display: none;
}

.dropdown li:hover .menu {
  display: block;
  float: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.0.8/js/all.js"></script>
<div class="dropdown">
     <ul class="menu dropdown menu-hover-lines" data-dropdown-menu>
       <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
       <li><a href="#">Collections</a>
          <ul class="menu">
            <li><a href="#">Autos</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Models</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Nature</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Extreme Sports</a></li>
          </ul>
       </li>
       <li><a href="#">About me</a></li>
       <li><a href="">Get in touch</a>
          <ul class="menu">
            <li><a href="#"><i class="fas fa-envelope fa-2x" data-toggle="tooltip" title="Email me!"></i></a></li>
            <li><a href="http://twitter.com"><i class="fab fa-twitter fa-2x" data-toggle="tooltip" title="Tweet me!"></i></a></li>
            <li><a href="http://instagram.com"><i class="fab fa-instagram fa-2x" data-toggle="tooltip" title="Message me!"></i></a></li>
          </ul>
       </li>
     </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: `.dropdown` is the entire set so, you should change the `hover` to li.

Comment: that was the magic step right there, thanks! I thought for sure I had the CSS right.

Comment: Your welcome . It's better to check code again and again when you facing problem.

Comment: Now, I'm having an issue where my last nav link gets pushed away while the "collections" menu is dropped. I tried using padding and margin but to no avail.